# Features locked until a certain date

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to disable a UIButton until a certain date. Any idea of how I can achieve that?

Comment: Just be aware that unless you check the date using a trusted web service, a user could game this by setting a future date in their system clock.

Comment: Also be sure you know what that date means — is it local time, UTC, ???

Answer (score 3):

You could check with a BOOL method in 2 different places
-in the IBAction
-in the viewDidLoad (or the method you use to initialize your interface with the button on it)

If you use the ibaction way, you will be able to trigger an alertpanel saying when the button will work.

If you use the viewDidLoad way, you will be able to disable the button when loading the view.
- you can hide the button, or set enabled to false

Here is how you can determine if the date has passed.

```
-(BOOL)shouldUseButton
    // assume the desired startDate is Jan 01, 2012.
    NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
    NSDate * startDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"01/01/2012"];
    [dateFormatter release];
    if ([startDate timeIntervalSinceNow] > 0) {
       return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

You could extend this method to take a date string and use it for several interface items that will become available on different dates

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to compare the current date `[NSDate date]` with the date that you would like the button to be enabled.

If the current date is before that date, you can set the button to Hidden or Disabled.